# Problem on Pigeon-Hole Principle

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

A college has 39 departments, and a total of 261 faculty members in those departments. Prove that there are three departments in this college that have a total of at least 21 faculty members.

This is a extra question in the fourth edition of 'Walk through Combinatorics', I can't think of how I should apply PHP here. I am self studying combinatorics through this book, it'd be helpful if I could get any hint on how to proceed.

Comment: Like if the number o fprofs in a department is x then x=21, y=21, z=21 or x+y+z=21?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: @insipidintegrator the second.  The first is obvious how to disprove (*suppose every faculty member was solely a member of the first department, then there is only one department with at least 21 faculty members and you will not be able to find three*).  The punchline is here that the average number of faculty members per department is just over $6.69$ and so the average number of faculty members in a trio of departments is going to be just over $20.07$.  Since number of faculty in trio of departments must be an integer there must be at least one case where that number is $21$ or higher.

Comment: @AnotherUser hey, thanks for advice. I edited the question.

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks for helping out. I am learning pigeonhole principle. It would be great if you could give any hint on how to apply pigeon hole principle here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the list of all possible trios of departments and their corresponding totals of number of faculty members.

If we add up all of these totals corresponding to each of the possible trios of departments, how many times did the number of faculty members of the first department contribute to the sum?  The second department's number of faculty members contribute to the sum?  What should the overall total of this sum of all possible trios' totals equal?

Supposing that every trio's total was actually $20$ or less, does that cause a problem?

> $\binom{38}{2}\cdot 261 > 20\cdot \binom{39}{3}$

Comment: Thank you so much. This makes sense.

Comment: An interesting extension to the problem would be to change the total number of faculty to $260$ instead of $261$ and see where that takes you.  The above approach doesn't work quite so directly but can still be massaged to work, again noting that the numbers involved here must be integers.

Comment: Instead of using combination, we could easily solve this problem by using pigeon hole principle. We should divide the 39 departments into units of 3(thanks to your hint), not we have 13 units and 261 faculty members. 261/13 = 20.07. As a person cannot be in fraction, we can conclude by pigeon hole principle that there exists at least one unit among the 13, that has 21 members in it.

Answer (score 3):

As the questions involves three departments, let us group the 39 departments as units of 3 departments each. Thus, we get 13 units with 3 departments each.

Now, applying Pigeon-Hole Principle, at least one unit exists which has 21 faculty members in it. **Hence proved**.

Note that we are asked that 21 faculty members are in 3 departments *in total* and not in 3 departments with 21 member each.